# SQL Table in CSV file shows NULL Rows as "&nbsp;" in Excel

Tags: sql, vb.net, excel, csv, gridview

Basically, I am displaying an SQL table in my VB.NET gridview, once its in my gridview, I then have a button that exports the results from visual studio into a CSV file, Everything in the CSV file looks fine, except any cell that is NULL in the SQL table now displays as:

```
&nbsp;
```

I tried to fix this in a stored procedure using the code bellow:

```
UPDATE EmailManagementTable
SET Excluded = ''
WHERE Excluded IS NULL
```

But even with this code I still get the same problem.

This is my Code for the Button that exports the gridview results to CSV:

```
    Response.Clear()
    Response.Buffer = True
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=gvtocsv.csv")
    Response.Charset = ""
    Response.ContentType = "application/text"
    Dim sBuilder As StringBuilder = New System.Text.StringBuilder()
    For index As Integer = 0 To GridView1.Columns.Count - 1
        sBuilder.Append(GridView1.Columns(index).HeaderText + ","c)
    Next
    sBuilder.Append(vbCr & vbLf)
    For i As Integer = 0 To GridView1.Rows.Count - 1
        For k As Integer = 0 To GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells.Count - 1
            sBuilder.Append(GridView1.Rows(i).Cells(k).Text.Replace(",", "") + ",")
        Next
        sBuilder.Append(vbCr & vbLf)
    Next
    Response.Output.Write(sBuilder.ToString())
    Response.Flush()
    Response.[End]()
```

I was wondering if I could get some assistance with this?

Thankyou in advance

Comment: Seems like the issue is in your code behind the button that exports the data. Perhaps you should post that.

Comment: No worries, I have posted the VB code into the question. @Nick.McDermaid

Comment: I've encountered this issue also with .NET making tables in a .asp page.  The only way I could find is to go through and remove them with a loop.  You can test for ASCII code 160 coming from your GridView and just substitue what you want in its place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem!

I edited some code inside my Export Button, Here's the code:

```
    Response.Clear()
    Response.Buffer = True
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=gvtocsv.csv")
    Response.Charset = ""
    Response.ContentType = "application/text"
    Dim sBuilder As StringBuilder = New System.Text.StringBuilder()
    For index As Integer = 0 To GridView1.Columns.Count - 1
        sBuilder.Append(GridView1.Columns(index).HeaderText + ","c)
    Next
    sBuilder.Append(vbCr & vbLf)
    For i As Integer = 0 To GridView1.Rows.Count - 1
        For k As Integer = 0 To GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells.Count - 1
            sBuilder.Append(GridView1.Rows(i).Cells(k).Text.Replace(",", "").Replace("&nbsp;", "") + ",")
        Next
        sBuilder.Append(vbCr & vbLf)
    Next
    Response.Output.Write(sBuilder.ToString())
    Response.Flush()
    Response.[End]()
```